# converted class to hooks, getting Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, react-hooks

I'm new in react hooks, here converting from class(class version works) to hooks, i'm not sure if i have done it correctly because when using 'then' in hooks it says 'Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) => Promise'.ts(2339)'

this is class version which works:

```js
import {
    getGraph,
    getFloorplan,
    changeActiveCamera,
} from "../redux/actions";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentSite: state.selection.currentSite,
    currentCamera: state.selection.currentCamera,

  
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getGraph: (site) => dispatch(getGraph(site)),
    getFloorplan: (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site)),
       changeActiveCamera: (site, id) => dispatch(changeActiveCamera(site, id)),

  };
}


loadGraph() {
    if (this.props.currentSite) {
      this.props.getFloorplan(this.props.currentSite.identif).then(() => {
        console.log("Fetched floorplan");

        this.props.getGraph(this.props.currentSite.identif).then(() => {
          console.log("Fetched model", this.props.realGraph.model);

          // new camera-related node & link status
          if (this.props.currentCamera) {
            this.props.changeActiveCamera(
              this.props.currentSite.identif,
              this.props.currentCamera.identif
            );
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

this is what i have done in order to convert it :

```js
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const currentSite = useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentSite);
  const currentCamera = useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentCamera);


const loadGraph = () => {
    if (currentSite) {
      dispatch(getFloorplan(currentSite.identif)).then(() => {
        console.log("Fetched floorplan");

        dispatch(getGraph(currentSite.identif)).then(() => {
          console.log("Fetched model", realGraph.model);

          // new camera-related node & link status
          if (currentCamera) {
            dispatch(
              changeActiveCamera(
                currentSite.identif,
                currentCamera.identif
              )
            );
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
```

After seeing video shared in comment, i changed the code and getting new error: 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at getFloorplan '
my code:

```js
   const currentSite = useSelector((state) =>      state.selection.currentSite);
   const currentCamera = useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentCamera);
   const getFloorplan = (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site));
   const getGraph = (site) => dispatch(getGraph(site));
   const changeActiveCamera = (site, id) =>
    dispatch(changeActiveCamera(site, id));
  
  const loadGraph = () => {
    if (currentSite) {
      getFloorplan(currentSite.identif).then(() => {
        console.log("Fetched floorplan");

        getGraph(currentSite.identif).then(() => {
          console.log("Fetched model", realGraph.model);

          // new camera-related node & link status
          if (currentCamera) {
            changeActiveCamera(
              currentSite.identif,
              currentCamera.identif
            );
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: In the original `getGraph` is a promise which means you can use `then`. In your second example (`dispatch(getFloorplan(currentSite.identif)).then`) you're trying to attach the `then` to the `dispatch` which is _not_ a promise. I'm still not clear on why you need to dispatch at every level.

Comment: @Andy if you were to convert that class to hooks, how would you convert it ?

Comment: shouldn't redux update something in it's state after you've done your dispatch? and your component should be subscribed to the new content?

Comment: [This video](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-replacing-mapdispatchtoprops-with-the-usedispatch-hook) might help.

Comment: @Andy do you mean like this const getFloorplan = (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site));
  const getGraph = (site) => dispatch(getGraph(site));  and inside loadGraph removing dispatch?

Comment: @Andy i edited and added new code according to the video you shared

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar i have added new code accroding to a video shared, does this help ? getting now : 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at getFloorplan '

Comment: I'm not sure I can help. We now both have the same understanding of how to change `mapDispatchToState` to `useDispatch`.

Comment: @Andy i did exactly as in video but getting 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' should getFloorplan  be inside useeffect somehow

Comment: this means that `getFloorPlan` is being called too many times, you should wrap it inside a `useEffect` to limit the number of renders

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar how to put this in useEffect: const getFloorplan = (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site));, can u provide working example so i can accept it ?

Comment: @joonas, i added it, i doubt it will magically fix your issues, will delete it if it gets downvoted tho

Comment: I thought simply adding useeffect there somehow would fix it, cuz its about Being called many times..

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt this simple solution will work, but here is my suggestions for refactors.

Please note that the way that your old class was written, that's not the recommended way of writing redux. Sure, the code will work, but it's not the "right" way in many people's opinions.

Refactor your actions

I would rather have my code written out like this :

YourComponent.tsx

```
const currentSite = useSelector((state) =>      state.selection.currentSite);
   const currentCamera = useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentCamera);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const loadGraph = () => {
     useEffect(() => {
       if(currentSite)
          getFloorPlan(currenSite.identif);
      
     }, [ dispatch, currentSite.identif])
// dispatch is in the dependency array to stop make eslinter complain, you can remove it if you want, others are used to control the number of renders
    
  };
```

YourComponentActions.ts

```
// assuming you are using redux-thunk here
const getFloorplan = ( site : YourType ) => async dispatch => {
  console.log("Fetched floorplan");
  // remove await if getImage is a sync function, try with await first and remove if it doesn't fit
  const response = await getImage(`api/graph/${site}/floorplan`, GET_FLOORPLAN);
  dispatch(getGraph(response))
}

const getGraph = (site : YourType) => async dispatch => {
   console.log("Fetched model", realGraph.model);
   // new camera-related node & link status
   if (currentCamera) {
      changeActiveCamera(currentSite.identif,currentCamera.identif);
   }
}

const changeActiveCamera = ( site: YourType, param: YourAnotherType ) => async dispatch => {
 // your logic here
}
```

Comment: my getFloorplan looks something like this : export function getFloorplan(site) {
    return getImage(`api/graph/${site}/floorplan`, GET_FLOORPLAN);
};

Comment: added and updated

Comment: my changeActiveCamera: export function changeActiveCamera(site, camera) {
  return getData(`api/cameras/${site}/${camera}`, CHANGE_CAMERA);
 } and my getGrpah:  export function getGraph(site) {
    return getData(`api/graph/${site}`, GET_GRAPHS);
 };

Comment: and doing those i got this: Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

Comment: i was assuming you were using the `redux-think` middleware, my solution wouldn't work if you don't have that middleware installed

Comment: yes this project is using that

Comment: can you tell me exactly where you are getting this issues?

Comment: hey you can delete your answer i got it working, one helped me, i solved this one ' 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at getFloorplan ' my code:' by 'Changing name of myconstants , it was creating recursive calls.'